# How to eliminate a repeat performance of bean in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, model-view-controller, mapping

Good day to all, there is a problem, my bean is executed twice, and I can not understand why. I'm new to spring boot and I'm afraid it's about misused annotations.

```
package com.Alfa.controllers;


import com.Alfa.tools.JsonParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class MainController {
    private final RankClient rank;
    private final GifClient gifClient;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(RankClient rank, GifClient gifClient) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.gifClient = gifClient;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{currency}")
    public String getGif(@PathVariable String currency, Model model) {
        JsonParser jsonParser=new JsonParser();
        System.out.println(currency);
        boolean res = jsonParser.isRankHigherToday(rank.getYesterdayJson(getYesterdayDate(), currency).getBody(), rank.getJson(currency).getBody());
        Map gif;
        if (res == false) gif = gifClient.getBrokeGif().getBody();
        else gif = gifClient.getRichGif().getBody();
        gif = (Map) gif.get("data");
        gif = (Map) gif.get("images");
        gif = (Map) gif.get("downsized_large");
        String GifSrc = (String) gif.get("url");
        model.addAttribute("src", GifSrc);
        return "index";

    }

    private String getYesterdayDate() {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }


}

@FeignClient(name = "RankClient", url = "${feign.client.rank.url}")
interface RankClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${feign.client.rank.json.latest}"+"${feign.client.rank.token}&base={currency}")
    ResponseEntity<Map> getJson(@PathVariable("currency") String currency);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${feign.client.rank.json.historical}" +
            "{date}" + "${feign.client.rank.json.historical.end}" + "${feign.client.rank.token}&base={currency}")
    ResponseEntity<Map> getYesterdayJson(@PathVariable("date") String date, @PathVariable("currency") String currency);
}

@FeignClient(name = "GifClient", url = "${feign.client.gif.url}")
interface GifClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${feign.client.gif.token}" + "${feign.client.gif.tag.broke}")
    ResponseEntity<Map> getBrokeGif();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${feign.client.gif.token}" + "${feign.client.gif.tag.rich}")
    ResponseEntity<Map> getRichGif();
}
```

`System.out.println(currency);` in my case returns two values, the first is what I need, but then returns favicon. ico.
I do not know where favicon.ico comes from and would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using a browser? It will make a request to `/favicon.ico` to retrieve the icon used to represent your web site in tabs, bookmark lists, etc.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson ,hmm, so should I just ignore the wrong execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web browser will make a request to `/favicon.ico` to retrieve the icon used to represent your web site in tabs, bookmark lists, etc. I suspect that's what's happening here.

You could avoid the problem by changing the URI so that your `@GetMapping` doesn't match anything beneath `/`. For example, you could use something like `currencies/{currency}`.

Alternatively, if you want or need to use `/{currency}`, you could validate that `currency` is a known currency code and return a 404 if it is not. Some input validation is generally a good idea, so that change is probably worth making no matter what URI the method is mapped to.